# Fusion Builder - imageslider with preview

Tags: wordpress, slideshow

our customer wants to have an imageslider, with a preview of the total imageslides below, on his site. They're using fusion builder to build up all of their sites. Now I'm not that familiar with wordpress nor fusion builder so I tried my best but could find a way just by using the fusion builder UI. They have elements for building imageslider and custom slides but I can't find anything for this preview thing below. I found this plugin [imageslider](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-responsive-image-slider/) which looks promising but I don't know how to put this in fusion builder.

So here is my setup. On the left side I want to insert the slider:

[image: fusion builder]

which should look like this:

[image: image slider]

Does someone know a way to do that or can give me any advice how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can easily include a shortcode in any of the text boxes in fusion builder UI.

- With Metaslider (plugin page here: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/).
- Or use Master slider (http://www.masterslider.com/template/showcase-with-horizontal-thumbs/).
- Or use the already included revolution slider. Here it shows how to select the thumbs option * https://www.themepunch.com/slider-revolution/navigation-thumbnails/*

Nevertheless these are all paid plugins..

If you manage to setup any of these sliders you can then generate a shortcode that you can insert in the textbox.

If you don't want to use those plugins because they are premium or sometimes add a lot of functionality *such as revolution slider* you can built a small plugin yourself, that generates a shortcode too, but I guess that's a bit too far considering your experience. Potentially there is a plugin that offers these features, but I could find them in the any of the free versions..